Criterion for cyclic groups in terms of its number of subgroups
Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Suppose that for every other group $H$ of order $n$, the number of subgroups of $H$ is at least as big as the number of subgroups of $G$. Does it imply that $G$ is cyclic? Using the fundamental theorem for abelian group, one can see that the claim is true if we assume both $G$ and $H$ to be abelian. But what happens in general?

Yes it does but I'll have to hunt for a reference

Okay, thank you.

I'd love to see one of the close voters take the time to explain their close vote. But I won't hold my breath.

I found a proof (from an old sci.math post of my own) that a finite group of order $n$ has at least $d(n)$ (the number of divisors of $n$) subgroups. This follows from the case $m=n$ in the result below. I am sure this result must be in the literature somewhere, but I have not been able to find it.
To answer your question, we  also need to prove that a group with exactly $d(n)$ subgroups is cyclic, which I have done in a corollary.
$\mathbf{Theorem}$. Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Then for any divisor $m$ of $n$,
there are at least $d(m)$ subgroups of $G$ of order dividing $m$.
Proof. Induction on $m$. Clear for $m=1$.
For $m>1$, let $p$ be a prime dividing $m$, and let $m=p^rk$ with $\gcd(p,k)=1$.
Since $d(m) = (r+1)d(k)$, it is sufficient to prove that for each $i$ with
$0 \le i \le r$, there are at least $d(k)$ subgroups of $G$ of order $p^i j$,
with $j$ dividing $k$.
So fix an $i$, let $P$ be any subgroup of $G$ of order $p^i$, let $N$ be the normalizer
in $G$ of $P$, and let $h = \gcd(|N|,k)$.
Since $h \le k < m$, by inductive hypothesis, the number $s$ of subgroups $S$ of $N$
of order dividing $h$ satisfies $s \ge d(h)$. For each of these we have
a subgroup $SP$ of $G$  of order $p^i j$, where $|S| = j$ divides $h$ and hence
$j$ divides $k$.
Now $P$ has $|G|/|N|$ distinct conjugates $P^g$ in $G$, and the $s|G|/|N|$ groups
$(SP)^g$ are all distinct. But $|G|/|N| \ge k/h$, so $s|G|/|N| \ge d(h)k/h \ge d(k)$, which
completes the proof.
$\mathbf{Corollary}$. If a finite group of order $n$ has exactly $d(n)$ subgroups then it is cyclic.
$Proof$. Note that all of the subgroups found in the proof of the theorem have a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, so if those are all of the subgroups of $G$ then $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup, and this is true for all primes $p$ dividing $|G|$.
So $G$ is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, and it is enough to prove the corollary for groups $P$ of prime power order $p^k$. Since $P$ has at least one subgroup of each order $p^i$ for $i \le k$, it has exactly one such subgroup. In particular it has a normal subgroup $Q$ of order $p^{k-1}$, which is cyclic by induction. Now any $g \in P \setminus Q$ must have order $p^{k+1}$ since otherwise it would generate an extra subgroup of smaller order, and so $P$ is cyclic.

A slightly stronger result (based on the number of cyclic subgroups) with a slightly harder proof can be found in: Richards, A Remark on the Number of Cyclic Subgroups of a Finite Group.

@Derek, thank you for your reply. The idea is nice, but i could not follow the argument given in the corollary which reduces the problem to p-groups. Yes, every subgroup that was constructed, contains a normal p-Sylow subgroup for some prime divisor p of its order. But how does it follow that such a subgroup contains a p-Sylow subgroup for EVERY prime divisor of its order?

@Steve, thank you for the reference.

@sagnikchakraborty As I said in the proof, if this lower bound on the number of subgroups of $G$ is exact, then all subgroups of $G$ must have been constructed in this way. So in particular, $G$ itself must be on the list of subgroups constructed. So $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since we could have chosen any prime dividing $|G|$ as $p$, this applies to all primes $p$ dividing $|G|$.
